# How to check if dom has a class using WebDriver (Selenium 2)?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am very new to Selenium, so my apologies if it's a silly question.
I have successfully wired up IntelliJ (Play! framework) with Selenium, and created some tests using firefoxDrivers.

I'm trying to check if the page had been validated properly.

long story short, I'm selecting an element like this:

```
WebElement smallDecel = firefoxDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#configTable tr:nth-child(2) td .playerDecelInput"));
```

I do some further operations (clear and change the value, submit the 'form'), and then I want to check if the TD the input sits in was given another class.

So, the question is - is there a simple technique I can use to find out if a WebElement / DOM has a class specified?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `FindElement(By.ClassName(//name of your class));` I would recommend that you either loop through and search the DOM for a set period of time or set a Thread.sleep(xxxx) and then look for the appended class.

Comment: Selenium can take care of waiting for the element to have the class name.  See [Selenium Explicit Wait docs](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)

Comment: +1 for @Julian's comment. Also the question is about checking the class of an element he already found. Your solution may find different elements with the same class, and not necessarily the element you already found.

Answer (score 33):

To expand on Sam Woods' answer, I use a simple extension method (this is for C#) to test whether or not an element has a specified class:

```
public static bool HasClass( this IWebElement el, string className ) {
    return el.GetAttribute( "class" ).Split( ' ' ).Contains( className );
}
```

Comment: just a quick edit, It should be `.split(' ')` and not `.Split(' ')`

Comment: his answer is correct, is .Split(' ') because this is C#, also take into account that you need to include System.Linq in the using directives in order for the .Contains to work.

Comment: Alternative for Java,
```
public static Boolean hasClass(WebElement el, String className) {
 return el.getAttribute("class").contains(className);
}
```

Answer (score 25):

Once you find the element, you can just call myElement.GetAttribute("class").  Then you can parse the string that is returned and see if it contains or does not contain the class name you care about.