# isSelected() method return false in selenium code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to test whether ROUND TRIP is selected or not. I can see ROUND TRIP is selected but still i am getting output as false why?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class IsSelected {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver f= new FirefoxDriver();
    f.get("http://www.makemytrip.com/");
    WebElement e = f.findElement(By.id("round_trip_button1"));
    System.out.println(e.isSelected());
    System.out.println(e.getText());
    System.out.println(e.isDisplayed());
    System.out.println(e.isEnabled());

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isSelected() applies to input
elements such as **checkboxes**, options in a **select** and **radio buttons.**

But in your case, it is implemented through 'a' (anchor text) so default isSelected() will not work.

For your case I checked 'a' properties,  you can easily custom implement isSelected() method by checking class value 'active'.
When round_trip_button1 id is selected, its class contains string 'active' and other case 'active' is missing.

Answer (score 3):

The element with `round_trip_button1` id is an `a` element, but you need an actual `input` with `radio` type instead:

```
f.findElement(By.cssSelector("a#round_trip_button1 input[type=radio]"));
```

UPD: to follow @aberry answer - you need to check an `a` tag to have an `active` class. Define a [function that would check for an element to have a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242288/how-to-check-if-dom-has-a-class-using-webdriver-selenium-2):

```
public static bool hasClass(WebElement el, string className) {
    return el.getAttribute("class").split(' ').contains(className);
}
```

And use it:

```
hasClass(f.findElement(By.id("round_trip_button1")), 'active');
```